# Abstract Nesting class in ormlite

Tags: java, ormlite

I have a project which contains three type of nested object, Location, category and value list.  Each object is a tree which contains a parent field and children field.  So I want to create an abstract class as a base class and i'm using ormlite to persist the records.

my Abstract class looks like this:

```
public abstract class SelectionValue {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "_id")
    private long id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String label;

    @DatabaseField
    private int sort;

    @DatabaseField
    private long valueId;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private Collection<SelectionValue> children;

    @DatabaseField (foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private SelectionValue parent;

    // setters and gettings 
}
```

But when i run the app i get this error from ormlite:

```
Foreign collection SelectionValue for field 'children' column-name does not contain a
    foreign field of class Location.
```

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Does the `SelectionValue` class contain a field `Location`?  That's how foreign fields work.  Otherwise, how would ORMLite know which children a location had?

Answer (score -1):

Your dataType for your children is wrong. According to the ORMLite manual: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Foreign-Collection
Your class should look like this:

```
@ForeignCollectionField
private ForeignCollection<SelectionValue> children;
```

Comment: tried this, also doesn't work,  the documentation states you can use ForeignCollection or Collection